# Button event not firing in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've added a jquery modal popup to save upload files for a specific device. The modal pops up, the cancel button works, but I cant figure out how to get the Save button to fire the onclick event...

This is what I've done:

```
     $(function () {
        $("#dialogCustUploads").dialog("destroy");
        $("#dialogCustUploads").dialog({
            title: "Upload Files",
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            width: 'auto',
            buttons: {
                Save: function () {
                    $(document.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID %>')).click();
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });

    function showCustUploads() {
        $(function () {
            $("#dialogCustUploads").dialog("open");
                    });
        $(".dialogCustUploads").parent().appendTo($("form:first"));  
    }


    <div id="dialogCustUploads" style="display: none">     
    <table style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Text="Client"></asp:Label>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblClientUploadName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label19" runat="server" Text="Certificate no" ></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCertificateNo" runat="server" Width="410px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text="Upload Option"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="lstUploadOption" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="410px"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" Text="File"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="fuPath" runat="server" Width="408px" />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1"></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" style="display: none;" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClick="btnSave_Click"  BackColor="White" />                          
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
</div>
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing or doing wrong... This is my first time on javascript... Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!! The savebutton does nothing....

EDIT

Thanks for everyone's help!
I have updated my button to remove the inline styling:

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClick="btnSave_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

And I've tried using the following which you have supplied to me:

```
    1. $("#<%=btnSave.ClientID%>").click();
    2. document.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').click();
    3. <asp:Button ID="btnSave" style="display: none;" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClick="btnSave_Click" ClientIDMode="Static"  BackColor="White" /> 
     document.getElementById('btnSave').click();
    4. $('<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').trigger("click");
```

but they all give me an error message which reads:

```
    Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'btnSave_Click' is undefined
```

When the form breaks the button reads as follows:

```
    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnSave" value="Save" onclick="btnSave_Click;" id="btnSave" />
```

Is there anything else wrong with what I'm doing?

EDIT

This is my source code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog("destroy");
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            title: "Message",
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
    function showMessage() {
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });
        return false;
    }

    $(function () {
        $("#dialogCustUploads").dialog("destroy");
        $("#dialogCustUploads").dialog({
            title: "Upload Files",
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            width: 'auto',
            buttons: {
                Save: function () {
                    document.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').click();
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });

    function showCustUploads() {
        $(function () {
            $("#dialogCustUploads").dialog("open");
                    });
        $(".dialogCustUploads").parent().appendTo($("form:first"));  
    }

</script>
```

My div where the for the button click event:

```
    <div id="dialogCustUploads" style="display: none">     
    <table style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Text="Client"></asp:Label>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblClientUploadName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label19" runat="server" Text="Certificate no" ></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCertificateNo" runat="server" Width="410px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text="Upload Option"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="lstUploadOption" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="410px"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" Text="File"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="fuPath" runat="server" Width="408px" />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1"></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" /> 

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
</div>
```

I call the modal popup from a click in a gridview:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvDeviceCalibration" runat="server" CellPadding="10" Width="90%" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  BorderWidth="1px">
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#3A4F63" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Size="7pt" Wrap="False" ForeColor="White" />
                            <RowStyle BackColor="White" Wrap="True" />
                                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC99" Wrap="True" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" ></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="InstrumentType" HeaderText="Instrument Type" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="InstrumentType"> <HeaderStyle Wrap="True" /></asp:BoundField>

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Make" HeaderText="Make" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Make"> 
                                    <HeaderStyle Wrap="True" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Location"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="SubLocation" HeaderText="Sub Location" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Sub Location"> <HeaderStyle Wrap="True" /></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="CalibrationIntervals" HeaderText="Calibration Intervals" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CalibrationIntervals"> <HeaderStyle Wrap="True" /></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="SerialNo" HeaderText="Serial No" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="SerialNo"> <HeaderStyle Wrap="True" /></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="WorkingRange" HeaderText="Working Range" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="WorkingRange"> <HeaderStyle Wrap="True" /></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Classification" HeaderText="Classification" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Classification"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="CalibrationDate" HeaderText="Calibration Date" DataFormatString="{0:yyyy/MM/dd}" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CalibrationDate">                                        
                                 <HeaderStyle Wrap="True" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="CalibrationHouse" HeaderText="Calibration House" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CalibrationHouse"><HeaderStyle Wrap="True" /></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Owner1s" HeaderText="Owner 1" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Owner1s"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Owners2" HeaderText="Owner 2" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Owners2"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="CreatedBy" HeaderText="Created By" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CreatedBy"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="UpdateStatus" runat="server" Height="22" BorderStyle="None" BackColor="Transparent"
                                            ImageUrl="~/Images/Sign-Select-icon.png" OnClick="SelectCalDevice_Click"  Width="22"  /><%-- --%>

                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>                                   
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upload">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="CustUploadFiles" runat="server" Height="22" BorderStyle="None" BackColor="Transparent"
                                            ImageUrl="~/Images/UploadFilesTrans.png" OnClick="SelectCustFiles_Click" Width="22"  /> 
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View ">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="CustViewFiles" runat="server" Height="25" BorderStyle="None" BackColor="Transparent"
                                            ImageUrl="~/Images/msgicon.png" ForeColor="Transparent"  Width="25" OnClick="ViewCustFiles_Click"  />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                            <EmptyDataTemplate>                                
                                <HeaderTemplate>There are no leads listed.</HeaderTemplate>
                            </EmptyDataTemplate> 
                        </asp:GridView>
```

And this is the SelectCustFiles_Click where I show the popup:

```
    protected void SelectCustFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton lb = sender as ImageButton;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)lb.NamingContainer;
        txtRowID.Text = row.Cells[0].Text;
        lblClientUploadName.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;

        PopulateUploadOptions();
        //modalCustUploads.Show();
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "popUpMessage", "showCustUploads();", true);
    }
```

And this is the click event I'm trying to call from script:

```
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Before attempting to save the file, verify
        // that the FileUpload control contains a file.
        if (fuPath.HasFile)
        {
            // Get the size in bytes of the file to upload.
            int fileSize = fuPath.PostedFile.ContentLength;

            // Allow only files less than 2,100,000 bytes (approximately 2 MB) to be uploaded.
            if (fileSize < 45497717)
            {
                // Call a helper method routine to save the file.
                //SaveFile(fuPath.PostedFile);
                SaveFile();
                fuPath.Dispose();

                lbljQMessage.Text = "Update successful";
                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "popUpMessage", "showCustUploads();", true);
                //modalCustUploads.Show();
            }
            else
                lblMessage.Text = "You did not specify a file to upload.";
        }
    }
```

I'm getting an error of 'btnSave' is undefined...

this is the scripts I'm using:

```
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

SOLVED

I found the problem... I appended the dialog in the wrong place.. Instead of this:

```
     function showCustUploads() {
        $(function () {
            $("#dialogCustUploads").dialog("open");
                    });
        $(".dialogCustUploads").parent().appendTo($("form:first"));  
    }
```

it should be:

```
     function showCustUploads() {
        $(function () {
            $("#dialogCustUploads").dialog("open");
                    }); 
    }
```

And instead of this:

```
     $(function () {
        $("#dialogCustUploads").dialog("destroy");
         $("#dialogCustUploads").dialog({
            title: "Upload Files",
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            width: 'auto',
            buttons: {
                Save: function () {
                  //  __doPostBack("<%=btnSave.UniqueID %>", "");
                    $($get("<%=btnSave.UniqueID %>")).click();
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

it should be:

```
     $(function () {
        $("#dialogCustUploads").dialog("destroy");
        var dlgUploads = $("#dialogCustUploads").dialog({
            title: "Upload Files",
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            width: 'auto',
            buttons: {
                Save: function () {
                  //  __doPostBack("<%=btnSave.UniqueID %>", "");
                    $($get("<%=btnSave.UniqueID %>")).click();
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        dlgUploads.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
    });
```

Thanks for everyone's help!!! Appreciate it!

Comment: Use only jquery or javascript, jquery syntex will  $('#<%=btnSave.ClientID %>')).click();

Comment: @user2042152: can you please confirm if you are okay to use a simple 'browser confirmation pop up' than using a 'jquery modal popup' to ask the confirmation for saving the file? In that case I have a suggestion. let me know.

Comment: @user3240361, Yes I am... I was using ajax control toolkit before, but due to a lot of compatability issues I have to find something else, as long as it's compatabil with IE 8 as well...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 document.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').click();

 Or

 $('#<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').click();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, this triggers the event, but its giving me an error of "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'btnSave_Click' is undefined"?

Comment: Remove OnClientClick from your button. Add $('<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').trigger("click"); inside script.

Comment: Removing the onclientclick and adding the above methods the button seems to be doing nothing....

Answer (score 3):

you are doing this wrong:

```
$(document.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID %>')).click();
```

you are mixing and confusing jquery and javascript selector, you should do like this with jquery:

```
$('#<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').click();
```

or like this with native javascript:

```
document.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').click();
```

**Note:** you can set buttton `ClientIDMode` to `Static` , then you can do like this as well:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" style="display: none;" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClick="btnSave_Click" ClientIDMode="Static"  BackColor="White" />
```

and in jquery:

```
$('#btnSave').click();
```

or in javascript:

```
document.getElementById('btnSave').click();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, clicking on the save button gives me an error now: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'btnSave_Click' is undefined"... any idea?

Comment: the event you have given onclient click of button is not defined remove that or add definition of btnSave_Click

Comment: Thanks I got it to give me a postback, but it's giving a full postback clearing the data before it gets to the save method?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').trigger("click"); // Make sure you use '#' as part of your jQuery selector
```

provided `$('<%=btnSave.ClientID %>')` is referring to the button, you can check it by inspecting `$('<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').length == 1`.

Comment: thanks its giving me an error of : "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'btnSave_Click' is undefined"

Comment: what do get when calling alert($('<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').length); ? Also which version of jQuery are you on?

Comment: The lenght returns as 0, I'm using the following 2 scripts:  <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: You're going to need just one, I'd go for the second one. My best bet is to use Chrome dev tools - in chrome just right click on the button and say 'Inspect element' in the context menu. Check the button it in there and compare it with <%=btnSave.ClientID%> they must be the same.

Comment: Hi, when I inspect the element it gives: <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnSave" value="Save" id="btnSave"> which I think the id's do match...

Comment: Sorry man - it must be $("#" + Id), if you hardcode it to $('#btnSave') - will it work?

Comment: If you have your button id as 'btnSave', the following $('#btnSave').length must be 1 or greater. There must be something fundamentally wrong if it still returns 0. Are you waiting for the document to be loaded before calling your JS? Also if you call: $(document.body).css('backgroundColor', 'green'); does it paint your document?

Answer (score 3):

Try just using

$("#<%=btnSave.ClientID%>").click();

and remove the give inline style of the button.

Comment: I removed the inline style, but it's giving me an error of: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'btnSave_Click' is undefined"

Comment: Try with OnClick inplace of OnClientClick.

Comment: It's still not doing anything, I tried using: __doPostBack('btnSave','OnClick'); which closed the dialog... but still not reaching the click event....

Comment: Can you share your server side and client side code for better understand.?

Answer (score 2):

IT should be

```
document.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').click();
```

instead

```
$(document.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID %>')).click();
```

Because you're using javascript, *BTW jQuery is javascript* but wrapping inside `$()` will create jQuery object, you were combining both.

Answer (score 2):

`OnClientClick` specifies a client-side javascript function to execute, but it looks like you're trying to use it to execute a server-side method. `OnClick` will execute a server-side method:

```
OnClick="btnSave_Click"
```

Comment: when I remove the OnClientClick and add the Click event, nothing happens, the button is not giving a postback nothing... I can click the button several times and nothing happens....

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try just using

```
   $("#btnSave").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to achieve the below:

1. When the user click on Upload image button in the GridView (gvDeviceCalibration) the user is shown with a jquery modal (or a popup).
2. If the user clicks on Cancel you do nothing , else if the user clicks on the Save button then go to the Code behind event handler 'btnSave_Click'

Possible Solution (change your 'Upload' template field in 'gvDeviceCalibration' GridView with below):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upload">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="CustUploadFiles" runat="server" Height="22" BorderStyle="None" BackColor="Transparent" ImageUrl="~/Images/UploadFilesTrans.png" OnClick="btnSave_Click" Width="22" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Save?')"  /> 
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In the above code we are making the Image button to do both the confirmation through 'OnClientClik' event and do the code behind call for the save method through 'OnClick' event.

In this case you need not use 'SelectCustFiles_Click' method or 'jquery modal.

Let me know in case of any issues

Comment: thanks for your suggestion! This would work, but I've got a certificate number and a date for when this upload should be done, and the posibility of the user first chooses the upload before entering the other data is there and it's not going to be user friendly if I unable the upload option for the other data... Any idea around this?

Comment: @user2042152: I could not get this part.! Can you explain in it again.?

Comment: I've got to save a certificate number, the date of when the certificate should be completed with the uploaded file. Doing the onclick from the upload control complicates it in respect of user friendlyness... I can't put the save method from the upload control as to requests that the other 2 fields must be completed and verified before saving these fields....